# Templated method within variadically templated class

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, variadic-templates

is there any way implementing this behaviour?

```
template < typename... Args >
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple < Args... > my_tuple;


    template < int n >
    static int bar () { return -5; };

};
```

What I need is this - I have variadically templated `MyClass` that contains method `foo` which is templated by another type (in my case only integer). Is this even possible? I have found simmilar solution but only for non-variadic class.

But this can't be compiled due to `bar`.

EDIT:
I compile on gcc 4.7.2

One should run the method like this `MyClass<int, int>::bar<4>()`

Could anyone possibly help me please?

Thanks in advance

EDIT2: full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <map>

template < typename... Args >
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple < Args... > my_tuple;


    template < int n >
    static int bar () { return -5; };

};

template < class A, int N >
static void foo()
{
    A::bar < N > ();
}


int main() { 

    foo< MyClass<int, int>, 4> ();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT3: error

```
$g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g -o test.out test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘void foo()’:
test.cpp:28:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo() [with A = MyClass<int, int>; int N = 4]’:
test.cpp:34:30:   required from here
test.cpp:28:2: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: do you mean method `bar`?

Comment: There is no `foo` in your code. And your code compiles fine for me on Clang 3.4

Comment: Compiles fine on gcc 4.7.2 with `-std=c++0x` also.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: full code and error provided, thanx guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling a template method from within a template without disambiguating the syntax as a template call (see the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for a great explanation).

You need the `template` qualifier here:

```
A::template bar<N>();
```